# Order of __init_subclass__ and descriptor __set_name__

Tags: python, subclass, python-descriptors

I have a number of dataclasses, all inheriting from a base class. `mapping` should be added dynamically to each of the subclasses and then used by the descriptor's `__set_name__` to set a key inside it.

Here's what this structure looks like:

```
class Model:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.mapping = {}

@dataclass
class ModelA(Model):
    property: str = Descriptor()

class Descriptor:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        owner.mapping[name] = 'foobar'
```

It seems that `mapping` is not there when the descriptor's `__set_name__` gets invoked. I tried using a metaclass for `ModelA`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        dict['mapping'] = {}
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
```

however that still did not work.

What am I missing here with regards to how my hierarchy is built? And how can I achieve the load order I am after?

N.B. I am using Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

`__set_name__` happens before `__init_subclass__`. [Here's](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) where that's documented:

> When using the default metaclass `type`, or any metaclass that ultimately calls `type.__new__`, the following additional customisation steps are invoked after creating the class object:
>
> - first, `type.__new__` collects all of the descriptors in the class namespace that define a `__set_name__()` method;
> - second, all of these `__set_name__` methods are called with the class being defined and the assigned name of that particular descriptor;
> - finally, the `__init_subclass__()` hook is called on the immediate parent of the new class in its method resolution order.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for pointing it out! How would I solve the problem in the most elegant way, though?